# Print specific array value via function argument

Tags: php

```
$menu = array(
    0 =>'top', 
    1 =>'photography', 
    2 =>'about'
);

<?php
function main_menu ($menu) {
    $return = '<div class="menu_entry">' . PHP_EOL .'';
        foreach( $menu as $key => $value)
        {
        $return .= '<a class="menu" href="index.php#' . $menu[$key] . '">' . $menu[$key] . '</a>' . PHP_EOL .'';
    }
  $return .= '</div>';
return $return;
}
?>

 <?php echo main_menu($menu[1]); ?>
```

What i basically want to do is to pass a specific array value when i'm echoing out the menu.
I'm building a single page website with anchors and i want to pass value's so i can echo out the "top"-link.

I'm stuck at the point on how to pass the $key value trough the function.

**edit: I'm trying to print specific links. I want a function that is able to print out an link but i want to specify the link to print via the function argument.

for example:

```
 <?php echo main_menu($key = '0'); ?>
 result:
 prints url: top

 <?php echo main_menu($key = '2'); ?>
 result:
 prints url: photography
```

**

(A lack of jargon makes it a bit harder to explain and even harder to google.
I got my books in front of me but this is taking a lot more time than it should.)

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Could you clarify more on "*I'm stuck at the point on how to pass the $key value trough the function.*"?

Comment: Are you trying to print the menu on the specified index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to pass the entire array and loop, or pass a single array item and not loop:

Single Item:

```
function main_menu ($menu) {
    $return  = '<div class="menu_entry">' . PHP_EOL .'';
    $return .= '<a class="menu" href="index.php#' . $menu . '">' . $menu . '</a>' . PHP_EOL .'';
    $return .= '</div>';

    return $return;
}

echo main_menu($menu[1]);
```

Entire Array:

```
function main_menu ($menu) {
    $return = '<div class="menu_entry">' . PHP_EOL .'';

    foreach($menu as $value) {
        $return .= '<a class="menu" href="index.php#' . $value . '">' . $value . '</a>' . PHP_EOL .'';
    }
    $return .= '</div>';

    return $return;
}

echo main_menu($menu);
```

You don't need `$menu[$key]` just use the `$value`.

Comment: Aah, yes ofcourse! I had it a for loop first where i used $menu[$i], i guess i didn't think it trough when i changed it.

Your first solution was what i was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo main_menu($menu); // You will get your links printed
```

Instead of

```
echo main_menu($menu[1]); // In this case error is occured like : **Invalid argument supplied for foreach**
```

**NOTE:** You can use  **$value** instead of **$menu[$key]**

Comment: If echo out $menu it shows all entries.
I want to pick out specific entries to print.

Comment: @Rico If you want to make specific links than you have to parse them in loop, update your question and I'll help you

Comment: @Rico I meant, explain what do you mean in specific links ? show me desirable output

Answer (score 0):

Should you not just be using `$value` inside your loop? And passing the entire array rather than one item of the `$menu` array?

```
$menu = array(
    0 =>'top', 
    1 =>'photography', 
    2 =>'about'
);

<?php
function main_menu ($menu) {
    $return = '<div class="menu_entry">' . PHP_EOL .'';
        foreach( $menu as $key => $value)
        {
        $return .= '<a class="menu" href="index.php#' . $value . '">' . $value . '</a>' . PHP_EOL .'';
    }
  $return .= '</div>';
return $return;
}
?>

<?php echo main_menu($menu); ?>
```